# Create Bitmap from Activity

Tags: android, facebook, android-activity, bitmap, background

I am a bit new to Android. But have developed a lot to iOS.

I have a parent activity (Activity1), it haves to load and setup another activity (Activity2) in the background. Then Activity2 is ready, it have to call a method that can take the Activity2 and return a bitmap image..
( I need this image for facebook share. )

So my questions are:

1.How do it initials a second activity with out showing it

2.How do I take the second activity and return it as a bitmap

```java
    public class Activity1 extends Activity implements OnClickListener, KKServerApiListener {

    private Activity2 facebookshareActivity;


   @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_summary);

      initView();


      /* Try 1 */
      facebookshareActivity = new KKFacebookShareActivity(route);
      /* Tried with some different things here */

      /* Try 2 */
      Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, KKFacebookShareActivity.class);
      myIntent.putExtra("number", route.id); 
      this.startActivity(myIntent);  
  }

  public void makeDialogShare(final Context context, final String str) {
        /*SETTING UP THE DIALOG */

        // ... //

        // ... //

        dialogButtonOk.setText("Share");
        dialogButtonOk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {

                /*  My try on getting my activity to a bitmap */
                View screenView = ****
                screenView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(screenView.getDrawingCache());
                screenView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

                /* Haven't worked  on this part just something i pasted from facebook */
                SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                        .setBitmap(bitmap)
                        .build();
                SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                        .addPhoto(photo)
                        .build();

                showDashboard(ctx, true);
                //finish();
            }
        });
        final Button dialogButtonCancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
        dialogButtonCancel.setText("Continue");
        dialogButtonCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                //finish();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Could you please link your `Activity1` code of what you've tried so far?

Comment: So basically what you want is to load (as it was visible) Activity2 and take a print screen of ti?

Comment: An Activity should really show something to the user that they can interact with. If you want to create an image consider using a Canvas or similar in your current activity

Comment: Yes thats correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you necessary need to get an Image of what you have in `Activity2` you can try inflating the layout of the Activity. Then create a Bitmap with the View just inflated and return it. Something like this in your code:

```
/*  My try on getting my activity to a bitmap */
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View screenView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_activity_layout, null);

        // add views and set rules (same as in the XML) to screenView
        ...

        screenView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        screenView.layout(0, 0, screenView.getMeasuredWidth(), screenView.getMeasuredHeight());

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(screenView.getMeasuredWidth(), screenView.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
        screenView.draw(c);

        ...

            /* Haven't worked  on this part just something i pasted from facebook */
            SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                    .setBitmap(bitmap)
                    .build();
            SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                    .addPhoto(photo)
                    .build();

            showDashboard(ctx, true);
```

`R.layout.your_activity_layout` is the layout you want to share.

**Note:** Since you are creating the view manually you will probably need to add some views and set configurations programmatically in order to recreate the layout (XML of you view).